# in git how to list the files which needs to be updated from remote repo?

Tags: git, file, pull

I would like to see all the files which I'm going to update in my local repo before I do 'git pull'. Is there any way?

Comment: I assume that you mean "in my local git workspace", i.e. the files you are working with?  rather than your local repo . . .

Answer (score 1):

Do a fetch instead of a pull:

```
git fetch upstream
```

This will download the changes without putting them into your working directory.

To compare them, do:

```
git diff HEAD upstream/branchname
```

Then you can merge them with:

```
git merge upstream/branchname
```

Comment: Which is exactly what git pull does in a single step.